# How does the erase-remove idiom work with ranges/constrained algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm trying to use a c++20 constrained algorithm for the erase-remove idiom:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.erase(std::unique(std::begin(v), std::end(v)), std::end(v));
```

but when I do a simple transformation:

```
v.erase(std::ranges::unique(v), std::end(v));
```

I get an [error](https://godbolt.org/z/qExT6v) that the arguments to `erase` don't match:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::erase(std::ranges::borrowed_subrange_t<std::vector<int>&>, std::vector<int>::iterator)'
```

A similar error is produced if the second argument is `std::ranges::end(v)`.

How can I get this to work?

---

The question originally used `remove` instead of `unique`, but there is an overloaded `std::erase` for all containers that makes that particular use case less motivating.

Comment: I can't see `std::ranges::remove` documented anywhere on cppreference, is it part of the standard? Looks like boost ranges has remove but not c++?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, it's [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.remove). It's listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges), on cppreference as well, but there isn't a specific page for it yet.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I switched to `ranges::unique` anyway, which is also in c++20.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option would be decomposing the subrange returned by `std::ranges::remove`/`unique`, and use those iterators:

```
auto [Beg, End] = std::ranges::remove(v, 42);
v.erase(Beg, End);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, this is much cleaner. It should be the new idiom IMO :)

Comment: @康桓瑋 No, it's fine. You just need to include `<ranges>`.

Comment: [But should we consider this as a gcc library bug?](https://godbolt.org/z/vex9s9)

Comment: @康桓瑋 I don't think so. `std::ranges::subrange` is declared in the `<ranges>` header. I assume that the GCC team decided not to include all of `<ranges>` in `<algorithm>`. Maybe they defined the `PairLike` protocol for `subrange` in a header that is not accessible by `<algorithm>`, but I don't see why that wouldn't be standard-compliant.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Part of the `subrange` structured bindings stuff is defined in the `<ranges>` header [itself](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e2e04288542667307df925f7d0a4b0fa2030f741/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ranges#L3323), while `<algorithm>` includes [`<bits/ranges_algo.h>`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e2e04288542667307df925f7d0a4b0fa2030f741/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/algorithm#L64), which includes [`<bits/ranges_util.h>`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e2e04288542667307df925f7d0a4b0fa2030f741/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ranges_algo.h#L36) where `subrange` is defined.

Comment: @metalfox, Yep I see. IMO, put `subrange`'s structured bindings stuff together with its definition should be convenient for users, since `std::ranges::remove/unique` return a  `subrange`, for a user like me usually want to structurally bind it without extra including `<ranges>`, and the compiler error message `cannot decompose inaccessible member 'std::ranges::subrange` also confused me.

Comment: @康桓瑋 IMO it would make sense to have these `tuple`-related specializations close to the `get` functions, which are [already](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e2e04288542667307df925f7d0a4b0fa2030f741/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ranges_util.h#L377) in the `<bits/ranges_util.h>` header. You might file a bug report requesting that. Even though it's not a bug, I'd say that, if there are no technical objections, they'll agree to move this stuff.

Comment: @metalfox Already filed a [report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97512) for this. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Wow, you got it fixed quickly! Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 13):

`std::ranges::unique` (and `std::ranges::remove`) returns a sub range from the first removed element to the end of the container so you need to use `std::begin` before passing to `std::vector::erase`:

```
v.erase(std::ranges::begin(std::ranges::remove(v, 42)), std::end(v));
v.erase(std::ranges::begin(std::ranges::unique(v)), std::end(v));
```

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work since `std::ranges::remove()` returns not iterator but range. But even if you try `v.erase(std::ranges::remove(...))` it will not work, because vector does not have `erase()` overload which takes range as parameter.

Instead, take a look at `std::erase()` (defined in `<vector>`). What you need is probably just `std::erase(v, 42)`.

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't really answer the question. This only works if I remove elements using an equivalent of `remove`. It doesn't work if I want to remove elements with an equivalent of `unique`. I've updated the question.